# How To Use @InjectMocks For A Dependency For Another Class To Be Mocked?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mockito, spring-test

Say I have a class :

```
   public class Boy
          {
                 @Inject 
                 @Named("birthDay")
                 BirthDay bday;
          }
```

And I want to mock it, but the problem is the BirthDay class itself uses a dependency which I want to mock and control as well, I cannot use both @InjectMocks and @Mock on the same class, how do you go about achieving the same?

Comment: what is the issue you encounter when you mock Birthday and make @injectmocks on Boy?

Comment: Say Birthday has a field Date that I want to mock and control, and it is injected in Birthday; how do I mock it in my test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to inject something in the mock?
You need to have two test classes for testing `Boy` and `BirthDay` classes.

Here you sould test logic of a `Boy` class

```
public class BoyTest{
  @Mock
  private BirthDay brithday;

  @InjectMock
  private Boy boy;
}
```

And logic of a `BirthDay` should have it's own Test class.

```
public class BirthDayTest {
  @Mock
  private Dependency dependency ;

  @InjectMock
  private BirthDay brithday;
}
```

So, you should assume that your mock returns some data that you need. And check that your Unit under test works as expected with given data.

Comment: I actually want to use a function in that mock (It accesses the DAO which saves the data eventually, I want to mock the same). Do I need to use a manual DAO for the same? Or can I use the when-then to do it?

Comment: I would rather use when-then clause. Because you are testing Boy class, so you should assume that your mock returns data that you need. Otherwise it's not unit-test anymore.

Comment: What if you want to prepare some dependencies for '@InjectMock' that not handle able by @Mock. For example Context.

Comment: @Kenji I'm not sure that I understood your question, but if you want to pass the real implementation, then you can initialize the field by yourself and mark it with `@Spy`, like this: `@Spy private Context context = new Context();`

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Then it can be consumable by "@Mocke" ed object?

Comment: @Kenji not by the mocked object, by the object annotated with `@InjectMocks`. If you need the partial-mock you have to use `@Spy` as well instead of `@Mock`

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I see! i'm looking for that. So for example if i want to prepare context for '@InjectMock' object i can put '@Spy' val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context ? Right?

Comment: @Kenji yes, correct. But, depending on your need, you may need to use integrations tests using your framework's runner.

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I have a question in stack overflow with title "Provide all dependencies for '@InjectMoks' objects with Mockito that can not provides with '@Mock'" and i face this problem and dono how to solve it.